# Why when I add ant design to my project I get problems with First Contentful Paint on Lighthouse panel?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Why when I add ant design to my project I get problems with First Contentful Paint on  Lighthouse panel?
What can be cause of this and how fix it in ant design?